Different monitor address on the same Java object in JMC
I got strange information from JMC report. In the Lock instances tab I see different Monitor addresses on the same object, why?
JMC screen
How it could be? Some tricks of GC work?
I double checked by System.identityHashCode, that JSContext is the same object on every sync call.
private static JSShapeData getShapeData(Shape shape) {
    CompilerAsserts.neverPartOfCompilation();
    JSContext context = JSShape.getJSContext(shape);
    // JSContext here
    synchronized(context) {
        Map<Shape, JSShapeData> map = context.getShapeDataMap();
        JSShapeData shapeData = (JSShapeData)map.get(shape);
        if (shapeData == null) {
            shapeData = new JSShapeData();
            map.put(shape, shapeData);
        }

        return shapeData;
    }
}

I tried to clarify this by searching.

Please add you code and other resources in the question it self. It is not a good practice to provide external links.

is it possible that there are 5 (or more) instances of JSContext?

No, I checked this several times...

The JVM may move objects during garbage collection so the address may change. I know this because I was involved in the design of the event. We thought it was better to have the monitor address (even if it may change) than not having it at all.
